# Express.js - request parameters not available

Tags: node.js, parameters, express, request

I'm trying to write an app in node.js https://github.com/findjashua/treasure-hunt-server

But when I use a url like user/bob, the req.params doesn't contain username: bob, but it'a empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You aren't assigning a parameter to the route path:

```
app.get('/users', user.list);
```

Add `/:username` like so for a parameter to be detected:

```
app.get('/users/:username', route);

// your route file
route = function(req, res) {
  // req.params.username
});
```